# I am very new to using PHP. I would like to create a comment box

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, wampserver

I am very new to using PHP.I would like to create a comment box for the user.
1. How do you save the comment in the database 
2. How do you see if there are any posts 
3. How do you display all posts to current page.
I am using Wampsever/MySQL Workbench.  May I have help? Thank you!

```
<?php
    require_once("db_connection.php");
    require_once("needed_functions.php");

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            //Take  Comment
            $comment_id = $_POST["comment"];

            if ($message == "" )
            {
                $query = "INSERT INTO comment (";
                $query .= "comment";
                $query .= ") VALUES (";
                $query .= " '{$comment}'";
                $query .= ")";

            //connect  &select 
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user_id");

            //query 
            $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Comment () VALUES();") 

            //close
            $result->close();
            }
        }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>JAE Movies</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif}
body {font-size:16px;}
.w3-half img{margin-bottom:-6px;margin-top:16px;opacity:0.8;cursor:pointer}
.w3-half img:hover{opacity:1}
</style>

<body style= "background-image:url(Roll.jpg)">

<!-- Sidebar/menu -->
<nav class="w3-sidebar w3-black w3-collapse w3-top w3-large w3-padding" style="z-index:3;width:300px;font-weight:bold;" id="mySidebar"><br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-button w3-hide-large w3-display-topleft" style="width:100%;font-size:22px">Close Menu</a>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h3 class="w3-padding-64"><b>JAE<br>Movies</b></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-bar-block">
  <a href="Homepage.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">Home</a> 
    <a href="signin.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">Sign In</a> 
    <a href="SignUp.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">Sign Up</a> 
    <a href="Information.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">Information</a> 
    <a href="Customer.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">Customer Service</a> 
    <a href="Admin.php" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-white">Administrator</a> 
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Top menu on small screens -->
<header class="w3-container w3-top w3-hide-large w3-light-blue w3-xlarge w3-padding">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-button w3-light-blue w3-margin-right" onclick="w3_open()">?</a>
  <span>JAE Movies</span>
</header>

<!-- Overlay effect when opening sidebar on small screens -->
<div class="w3-overlay w3-hide-large" onclick="w3_close()" style="cursor:pointer" title="close side menu" id="myOverlay"></div>


<!--Start Inserting Page Content-->
<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:340px;margin-right:40px">

 <!-- Header -->
  <div class="w3-container" style="margin-top:80px" id="userhome">
    <h1 class="w3-jumbo w3-text-white"><b>Lion King</b></h1>
  </div>

  <!--Image-->

 <div class="w3-half">
      <img src="Images/LionKing.jpg" alt="LionKing" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <!--Description-->

<div class="w3-half">
<p style="color:white";>Lion cub and future king Simba searches for his identity. His eagerness to please others and penchant for testing his boundaries sometimes gets him into trouble.</p></br>

    </div>

    <!--Buttons-->
 <div>
 <button type="submit"><a href= "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110357/videoplayer/vi3764362265?ref_=tt_ov_vi">WATCH TRAILER!</a></button>
 <button type="submit"><a href= "http://123moviesfree.com/watch/the-lion-king-1994-i.1-online-free-123movies.html">WATCH MOVIE</a></button>

    </div>

<!--Comments-->

<div>

<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" form="usrform">
Enter comment here...</textarea>

<form action=" " method="post" id="com">
  <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="texty" >
</form>


</div>
```

Comment: If you’re just getting started with PHP development and want to make applications, pick a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that suits your style and needs. These come with many examples that illustrate how to do exactly what you’re asking for here. What you've created is a confusing strew of HTML, CSS, PHP, and SQL, there's no separation of concerns, a common mistake when trying to learn PHP. A framework helps you stay focused on the task at hand and keeps your code maintainable both by you and others.

Comment: @Alton Joyner As i understood your question you want a comment box below image or video. just like nowdays movie websites.Am i right

Comment: @PavanBaddithat is correct

Comment: @Alton Joyne then sure within few mins i'll post answere

Comment: @PavanBaddi thank you

Comment: @PavanBaddi I keep receiving an error around line 63-71. I took the link for the sql link out.

Answer (score 0):

When using database connections in PHP make sure you do the following

```
//connect  &select 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

//query 
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tbl_name () VALUES();") // Add the update comment here
//close
$result->close();
```

Always remember to :

connect 
select 
query 
close

you'll then need to get all of the comments for the page using the same process but with the select process rather than insert.

Comment: On the right track, but far from an actual answer. This question is probably too broad.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Evans. I'm thinking the comment can post to another page. Allowing the comment to be seen there.

Comment: I think we need to break this into 3 questions. 1 how to save the comment 2 how to see if there are any posts and 3 how to desplay all posts. Can you also put in the 2 files at the top of your script. Add them to your question as well.

Comment: @ChrisEvans ok that does make sense?

Answer (score 0):

So their is a code which save `comment` in database , displays in database and if comment is not posted or not available than it show `NO COMMENT AVAILABE` message.

I'M USING PHP AND MYSQLI HERE. Recommend not to use `mysql` as it is deprecated.

THE DATABASE TABLE IMAGE

[image: DATABASE TABLE IMAGE]

CODE OUTPUT IMAGE

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

php file:

```
    <?php
    $link = new mysqli ('localhost','root','admin','demo1');

    if($link->connect_error){
        die ("Connection failed".$link->error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $comment = mysql_escape_string($_POST['comment']);  

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES ('$comment')";

        if($res = $link->query($sql)){

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error".$sql."<br>".$link->error;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>PHP</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="loinKing" style="width:100%;height:300px;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Type Comment.."  class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="POST" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Left-aligned -->

    <?php
        //HERE SHOW OR DISPLAY THE COMMENTS
        $q = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC";
        if($r = $link->query($q)){
            if($r->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <img src="images/img_avatar1.png" class="media-object" style="width:60px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <p>Date Posted : <?php echo $row['date'];?></p>
                            <p>Comments :<?php echo $row['comment'];?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
    <?php
                }   
            }
            else
            {
    ?>
                <h4>No Comments Available</h4>
    <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error".$sql."<br>".$link->error;
        }
    ?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### I hope all of your questions are answered. If not then reply to me....

Comment: thank you. I keep receiving an error on line 71. I took think sql link check out.

Comment: may it be because i'm using MySQL rather than MYSQLi?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    require_once("db_connection.php");
    require_once("needed_functions.php");


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $comment = mysql_escape_string($_POST['comment']);  

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES ('$comment')";

        if($res = $link->query($sql)){

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error".$sql."<br>".$link->error;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Movies</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins">
<style>
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif}
body {font-size:16px;}
.w3-half img{margin-bottom:-6px;margin-top:16px;opacity:0.8;cursor:pointer}
.w3-half img:hover{opacity:1}
</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="loinKing" style="width:100%;height:300px;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Type Comment.."  class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="POST" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Left-aligned -->

    <?php
        //HERE SHOW OR DISPLAY THE COMMENTS
        $q = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC";
            if($r->num_rows > 0){
                while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <img src="images/img_avatar1.png" class="media-object" style="width:60px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <p>Date Posted : <?php echo $row['date'];?></p>
                            <p>Comments :<?php echo $row['comment'];?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
    <?php
                    }   
                }
            else
            {
    ?>
                <h4>No Comments Available</h4>
    <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error".$sql."<br>".$link->error;
        }
    ?>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: `$r = $link->query($q)` is important because it executes the query i'm not getting any of the error. Check i have added my database table and output  image..

Comment: @PavanBaddiok I see what you're saying. Now i just keep getting an error with this, line 2           $link = new mysql ('localhost', 'root','JAEMovie');

Comment: '$link = new mysqli ('localhost','root','admin','demo1');' check your syntax I have used mysqli and u are using mysql .  you just copy the the code create a dummy database demo in phpmyadmin and then try this works not problem... I have cross chexkedchexked it 3 times..

Comment: See I'm using WampServer and MySQL Workbench. I have other pages tied to this also.

Comment: It is so simple error is in front of you . do as I told u comment those require once () and the syntax is it is mysqli not MySQL check properly. Here is the syntax $link = new mysqli ('localhost','username','password if not their than leave a white space','database name'); their is error in your code not mine..

Answer (score 0):

**Error For some reason I'm not finding:**
[image: Error For some reason I'm not finding]

Your screenshot is exactly what I am looking

Comment: It is so simple error is in front of you .  do as I told u comment those require once () and the syntax is it is mysqli not MySQL check properly.    Here is the syntax $link = new mysqli ('localhost','username','password if not their than leave  a white space','database name');       their is error in your code not mine